# GUI errors. Can't undraw 'Rectangle' objects

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I imported a GUI library and I can't 'undraw' any objects that are a 'Rectangle'. I attached the link to the library I'm using and an example of what the error looks like. Thanks for any and all help given.

https://mcsp.wartburg.edu//zelle/python/graphics.py

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin("Test", 200, 200)

rect = Rectangle(Point(50, 50), Point(150,150)).draw(win)
stop = win.getMouse()
rect.undraw(win)
```

[This is the error that I'm getting from IDLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enf9a.jpg)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be valid code - what is `kaden`?  One possible problem I see is that `rect` isn't actually the `Rectangle` you created, it's the result of calling `.draw()` on that object.

Comment: 'kaden' was supposed to be 'rect'. It's worked for other objects like 'Text' or 'Line' objects when you save it as a variable, then you could later use .undraw() to remove it from the window.

Comment: Were you calling `.draw()` in the same statement for those other objects?  Try splitting it into two - `rect = Rectangle(...)` and `rect.draw(...)`.

Comment: I still get the same error so I don't think that that's it

Comment: You need to post the actual error message, then.

Comment: K, I linked a picture of the error message

Comment: Oh, just get rid of the `win` parameter then - it doesn't need that, the object can only be undrawn from the window where it's currently drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
rect.undraw(win)
```

the rectangle is already associated with `win` so you don't supply that as an argument to `undraw()`.  Instead simply do:

```
rect.undraw()
```